# Error in copying jars to /home/hadoop/lib emr

Tags: hadoop, bootstrapping, emr

I am copying my external jars to `/home/hadoop/lib` directoy in `emr` as a `bootstrap` process. But it is showing following error during bootstrap process

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder$3 has interface com.google.common.base.Ticker as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.<clinit>(CacheBuilder.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:46)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:861)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:256)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.fetchFile(ScriptRunner.java:39)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.main(ScriptRunner.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

Can anyone help me why it is happening?

Comment: Looks to be a problem with Guava library versions. Verify the Guava version of the hadoop installation against what you compiled the external jars against.

Comment: Can you tell me in detail, I am just copying external jars to lib directory. Just after copying I am getting the error.

Comment: I know lib folder is in classpath, so may be it is checking all the jars at bootstraping. But how to remove it.

Comment: How are the external jars built? Using Maven? If yes, you could look at the Guava version in POM. Also try searching for Guava libraries in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was that Mahout 0.7 is using an older version of Guava. I replaced Mahout 0.7 with 0.8 and it worked.